# Alarm Manager goes off as i click the Button

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I have the code set on a button which sets the alarm manager to send broadcast and activate the WiFi on the device. I have set the delay for 1 min but code but the alarm goes off as soon as I click the button

Here's the code on button:

```
public void start(View view){
        AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(this,MyReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent TurnWiFi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent1, 0);
        long milli = 60000;
        alarm.set(AlarmManager.RTC,milli,TurnWiFi);
    }
```

The code in Receiver:

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i("BroadcastReceiver","------------>In on receive method<-------------");
        WifiManager wifi_man = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        wifi_man.setWifiEnabled(true);

    }
```

Comment: you can try and use alarm.setExact() instead of alarm.set() see if thats solves your problem: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setExact(int, long, android.app.PendingIntent)

Comment: setExact() and setWindow() are only to be used on API level 19(Kitkat) and above since the alarm delivery by default is inexact but i am running this code on a jelly bean device so set() should work normally as intended

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in alarm.set(AlarmManager.RTC,milli,TurnWiFi); milli is already passed
use Calendar for less complexity.

this should solve your problem:
`alarm.set(AlarmManager.RTC,System.currentTimeMillis() + milli,TurnWiFi);`

**UPDATE:**

Explanation:

> If the stated trigger time is in the past, the alarm will be triggered immediately

trigger for AlarmManager.RTC (Real Time Clock) type is time of day represented by milliseconds. and 60000 millis is literally in the past.

according to documents, System.currentTimeMillis() + 60000 goes off in next 60secs

> System.currentTimeMillis()
>   **Returns the current time** in milliseconds since January 1, 1970 00:00:00.0 UTC.

Comment: please can u explain why do i need to use System.currentTimeMillis(); why cant i put milliseconds directly

Comment: @HVenom cause trigger is time of day, millis is in the past and your alarm goes off immediately.